# Excel: Cumulative sum of min values of 2 columns without needing to create an extra column

Tags: excel, excel-2016, cumulative-sum

I have two columns that I need to find the minimum value of, and then create a cumulative sum of them. I can do this by creating an extra column to hold the min value and then cumulative sum them, e.g.:

```
Col1 Col2 min(Col1, Col2) Cumulative Sum of Mins
   1    3               1                      1
   4    2               2                      3
   3    5               3                      6
```

Is there a way of doing this without creating the extra column?

I've tried `sum(if(A$2:A2 < B$2:B2, A$2:A2, B$2:B2))` which I found (and modified) from another similar-but-not-similar-enough question, but this appears to just find the lowest value in the entire range and output that into a single cell; copying and pasting the formula into the other fields results in:

> A value used in the formula is of the wrong data type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put this in C2 and copy down:

```
=IFERROR(--C1,0)+MIN(A2:B2)
```

[image]

---

Another approach is with SUMPRODUCT

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:A2<$B$2:B2)*($A$2:A2)+($A$2:A2>$B$2:B2)*($B$2:B2))
```

But this is an array type formula and as such every line this is copied down will increase the number of calculations exponentially.  If too many lines are used the user will see a time delay in the calculations.

[image]

Comment: Totally unrelated and random question, but how would this work if you didn't have column headers in row #1?  Now your first data would be in `A1:B1`, and your formula would need to be `--C0`, which doesn't work.  I tried deleting the first row, and it works, but the first row now has a formula of `=IFERROR(--#REF!, 0)+MIN(A1:B1)`, which isn't nice.

Comment: This assumes that there is a first row, which is why I stated put it in C2 not C1.  If there are not headers then the OP will need to put `=MIN(A1:B1)` in C1 and the other formula in C2.

Comment: Thanks - I don't know why I didn't think of adding the current min val to the previous row's calculated column myself!